# creating multiple folders inside current directory in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, directory

I want to make some folders using a loop in current directory in c++. I have made a code but getting  the following error.

> cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'void CreateFolder(const char*)'

My code is:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<cstdio>
 #include<cstring>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include<cstdlib>
 #include<fstream>
 #include <sstream>
 using namespace std;

#define total 28

std::string to_string(int i) {
   std::stringstream s;
   s << i;
   return s.str();
}


void CreateFolder(const char * path)
{
    if(!CreateDirectory(path ,NULL))
    {
        return;
    }
}


main()
{
    string folder_name;
    string suffix = ".\\"; // for current directory

     for(int i=0;i<=total;i++)
    {
        folder_name=suffix+to_string(i);
        CreateFolder(folder_name);

    }

}
```

How will I create those folders named 0,1... to 28?

Comment: As a hint: What does a backslash mean inside a string or character literal? Think about that for a moment.

Comment: Replace `CreateFolder(folder_name);`  by `CreateFolder(folder_name.c_str);` and lookup the [`string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method.

Comment: BTW the title of this question is totally misleading. And this should be tagged C++. It's more of a C++ question than a WINAPI question.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear? Your next task is to learn how to understand error messages.

Comment: Off-topic: Using the current directory is wrong. There's no safe way to use it, since you cannot impose any restrictions or deduce any guarantees. At any point it will point to *some* directory, and you do not control which one it is, or when it changes. Use absolute paths.

Comment: @IInspectable No. For a console application, the current directory is routinely used as input to the program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A console application suffers from the same issues as a program running in the Windows subsystem. You have no control over the process-wide current working directory. You are quoting a convention that's neither contractual, nor can it be enforced.

Comment: @IInspectable There are all sorts of things that malicious parties can do to sabotage external processes. That much is certainly true. But it is a perfectly reasonable for a console application to adopt a convention that relies upon the parent process specifying a working directory. I have no doubt that when you work with console applications at the command shell, you are happy to provide filenames relative to the working directory of your command shell. Or perhaps you don't. Perhaps you always supply absolute paths.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You merely re-iterated, that there is (allegedly) a convention that is neither contractual nor enforceable. Unless **you** can guarantee, that no thread in your process will ever change the current working directory, you'll have to live with the fact, that it's unsafe to use. And since you cannot even guarantee, which threads run in your process, it'd be moot to continue this conversation. If this is factually incorrect, please provide reference documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable So I am right in assuming that you never ever use relative paths. When in the command prompt you always write `C:\foo> cd C:\foo\bar` rather than `C:\foo> cd bar`. That must get pretty tedious for you.  Then again, I guess you find it impossible to use a command line interpreter for fear of some stray thread changing the process working directory in a race condition.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I wasn't looking for assumptions. I had specifically asked for reference documentation. As always, when wrong, and pressed to back your claims with verifiable facts, you back out, move on to personal attacks, and the like. Anyway, good luck in life. I'm out here.

Comment: @IInspectable I already agreed with what you state, that the process working directory can be changed by any code running in your process. Who could possibly argue with that? At the command prompt, do you always use absolute paths, or do you ever use relative paths? I bet you won't give me a straight answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *"At the command prompt, do you always use absolute paths, or do you ever use relative paths?"* - How is an answer to that question helpful in progressing the discussion? For the record, I tend to provide fully qualified path names everywhere. It's one rule, that always works, instead of two, where doing one thing sometimes fail. I'm puzzled as to why you haven't implemented that **obvious** reduction of complexity into your work life yet.

Comment: @IInspectable So when you are at a prompt, 5 levels deep into a drive, you type `cd C:\foo1\foo2\foo3\foo4\foo5\foo6` rather than `cd foo6`? OK, that's up to you. If you call that reduction in complexity, so be it. Maybe I've just been lucky, but `cd foo6` has always worked for me.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed. `cd` is interpreted by cmd.exe. Are you saying that cmd.exe is immune to arbitrary threads changing the working directory? I don't think I am turning things around. From where I am sitting you said something silly and cannot bring yourself to admit it. Still, enjoy typing out all those directory names in the name of reduction in complexity!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Mind to remind me, what that *"something silly"* was? This time around, **producing facts**, instead of challenging some random user's command line habits?

Comment: @IInspectable Your very first comment. Pretend that the program being written is indeed `cmd.exe`. Pretend that its job is to parse the command `cd foo`. What choice does `cmd.exe` have but to use a relative path? So it strikes me as a little silly to claim that no program ever should use a relative path.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What's there to pretend? *cmd.exe* is not required to rely on the current working directory, to safely implement `cd foo`. And that comment prescribing to use absolute paths was said in context of this question. There's nothing wrong using a relative path, relative to a command line parameter, for example. Just don't use a relative path based on an unknown (which is what you seem to be absolutely fine with, and even condone).

Comment: @IInspectable `cmd.exe` does indeed rely on the current working directory. I'm intrigued to know how it would avoid doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly pass a `std::string` as `char*`. By using `c_str()` function you can retrieve the raw `char*` from `std::string`.

```
//std::string -> const char*
CreateFolder(folder_name.c_str());
```

Comment: getting the following error while compiling: error: cannot convert 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '1' to 'BOOL CreateDirectoryA(LPCSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)' @Doncot

Comment: Oh, sorry. Looks like you're using Multi-char settings (= not-UNICODE). Fixing my answer.

Comment: @Doncot: *"you're using Multi-char settings"* - It's called *Multi-Byte* (as in MBCS), which really is DBCS in Windows. And it's the one setting you do **not** want to use. The real fix is to use `std::wstring` and call `CreateDirectoryW`.